# PostgreSQL nested tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a grid that looks like the picture attached. Each level of the grid corresponds to a table.

**Studies table:** agent, study, ind_no, ind_sponsor, current_status

**Sites table:** study, amtrackid, name, pi, dsa, status, irbappcr, ibc, obarac, ohrp, ib, prot, ic, global1572

**Labs table:** amtrackid, labid, name, cap, clia, lnv

**Investigators table:** amtrackid, personid, name, cv, ml, fd, dot, hspt, pisort

How can I generate a CSV file that loops thru the table, and provides an output similar to the nested grid?

```
-Agent     Study        IND_no  ND_sponsor   Current_Status-------------------------------------------------------------
-9-cis-UAB30;UWI10-16-01R; 101064;  DCP;        Completed------------------------------------------------
------------------Site                                          PI             ...-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----University of Wisconsin Hospital and Clinics;Kolesar, Jill M, PharmD... ------------------------------------     ---------Lab  CAP CLIA  LNV------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------UAB University of Alabama Hospital Lab ...-----------------------------------------------------------------
---------Investigator   CV  FD-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------Rahman (Davis), Zahra...
```

Labs and Investigators are in the same level.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried to create a function that would loop through it, but the query runs forever. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dw_regtrack.dash_parsing_quicklist(userName character)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  superData RECORD;
  studyData RECORD;
  siteData RECORD;
  siteData2 RECORD;

BEGIN
truncate table dw_regtrack.dash_output_quicklist; 

for superData in (select agent, study, ind_no, sponsor, status, user_name as uname from dw_regtrack.qlstudies st left join dw_regtrack.user_studies us ON st.study=us.study_name)
loop
    INSERT INTO dw_regtrack.dash_output_quicklist(agent,inform1,inform2,inform3,inform4,inform5)
        (select agent, study, ind_no, sponsor, status,user_name from dw_regtrack.qlstudies st left join dw_regtrack.user_studies us ON st.study=us.study_name where superData.uname='gsamara');

    --(select agent, study, ind_no, sponsor, status from dw_regtrack.qlstudies st left join dw_regtrack.user_studies us ON st.study=us.study_name where user_name='gsamara');

    for studyData in (select study, amtrackid, name, pi, status, irbappcr, ohrp, ib, prot, ic, global1572, 1572, ibc, obarac, dsa from dw_regtrack.qlstudysites2)
    loop

        insert into dw_regtrack.dash_output_quicklist(agent, inform1, inform2, inform3, inform4, inform5, inform6, inform7, inform8, inform9, inform10, inform11,inform12,inform13,inform14,inform15)
        (select '', study, amtrackid, name, pi, status, irbappcr, ohrp, ib, prot, ic, global1572, 1572, ibc, obarac, dsa from dw_regtrack.qlstudysites2 where studyData.study=superData.study);

        for siteData in (select amtrackid, labid, name, cap, clia, lnv from dw_regtrack.qlstudysitelabs)
        loop        
            insert into dw_regtrack.dash_output_quicklist(agent, inform1, inform2, inform3,inform4,inform5,inform6,inform7)
            (select '','', amtrackid, labid, name, cap, clia, lnv from dw_regtrack.qlstudysitelabs where siteData.amtrackid=StudyData.amtrackid);

        end loop;

        for siteData2 in (select amtrackid, personid, name, cv, ml, fd, hspt, dot, pisort from dw_regtrack.qlstudysiteinvests2)
        loop    
            insert into dw_regtrack.dash_output_quicklist(agent, inform1, inform2, inform3, inform4, inform5, inform6, inform7, inform8,inform9,inform10)
            (select '', '', amtrackid, personid, name, cv, ml, fd, hspt, dot, pisort from dw_regtrack.qlstudysiteinvests2 where siteData2.amtrackid=studyData.amtrackid);

        end loop;
    end loop;
end loop;

Return 1;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION dw_regtrack.dash_parsing_quicklist(character)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: This should be done at your application/UI layer, not in your database.

Comment: So there is no way to save the data in that format to a CSV file, directly from the database?

Comment: I'm not going to say that there definitely isn't, but the only way I can think to do it, via a stored procedure, would be horrific code and horribly slow and wouldn't scale well. Honestly any outside script/code/application to do this would be preferable as this format is just not in an RDBMS's wheelhouse.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will try from the application side.